# How to open a Tkinter askopenfilename dialog compatible with Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to write a simple Python Tkinter file chooser that is compatible both with Python2.7 and Python3.x

**Python3 Version**

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename(title="Select file")
root.update()
root.destroy()
```

**Python2.7 Version**

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename(title="Select file")
root.update()
root.destroy()
```

How can I come up with a unified solution?

Comment: Put one version of imports in a `try` block and the other version of imports in `except` block.

Comment: Thank you @Guglie! This is a rare sample I can find for `askopenfile()` (especially on Python 2). You saved my day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to import `Tk` and `askopenfilename` as for Python 3.x at first. If you get an `ImportError` (there is no `tkinter` and `tkinter.filedialog` modules), try to import them as for Python 2.x. (from `Tkinter` and `tkFileDialog` modules).
Here is the example:

```py
try:
    # Python 3.x
    from tkinter import Tk
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
except ImportError:
    # Python 2.x
    from Tkinter import Tk
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename(title="Select file")
root.update()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: Just for completeness, if the class/submodule/function to import has a different name, you can also use `from ... import ... as ...` to have a uniform name to use in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do this:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    # Import module
    from Tkinter import *
elif sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    from tkinter import *
else:
    print ("System Config Error", str(sys.version_info))
    raise SystemError
```

The `else` block can be omitted if you want.