# filedialogue non-existent in Tkinter Ver 8.5?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to use the filedialogue functions included in tkinter to add a File Selection button to my program However, I cannot find the filedialogue within the tkinter module.

Here are a few details of my scenario:

1. I recently updated to Python 3 and have appropriately corrected my paths, environments, and reinstalled Tkinter using Pip3.
2. I noticed that my Python 2.7 module is "Tkinter" and my Python 3 is listed "tkinter". However  both versions of Tkinter does not have filedialogue anywhere in them.
3. Inside the Tkinter 8.5. Documentation, it states that the function does exist, so I should be seeing it somewhere.

Did I download the wrong module? Unlikely. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Below I attached some pictures that include me attempting to download both Tkinter and tkinter as well as screenshots of the contents of the modules. I checked both tkinter and tkinter.Tk's contents for it.

Me reinstalling Tkinter and tkinter. I seem to be up to date:

[image: Me reinstalling Tkinter and tkinter. I seem to be up to date.]

A photo showing that "filedialogue" is non-existent:

[image: A photo showing that "filedialogue" is non-existent.]

Comment: Some parts of tkinter needs to be imported seperatly in python 3, like `from tkinter import ttk`. Same is for `filedialog`. [Simliar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647028/how-to-open-a-tkinter-askopenfilename-dialog-compatible-with-python-2-and-python/56647290)

Comment: You can't install tkinter with pip

Comment: @BryanOakley In retrospect, seeing as it is already a built-in Python module, it was stupid of me to try using Pip to download it, but I was simply going down a mental check-list of possible reasons I couldn't find it in the Module list.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates  how you're trying to use the file dialog. Are you certain that you are importing it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

With python 3, this following syntax has always worked for me

```
from tkinter import filedialog

directory = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
```

Perhaps you are mis-spelling filedialog as per your question

Comment: Oh wow. I just assumed since I didn't see it in the list it didn't exist. It worked. *facepalm*. Thank you. :)

Comment: @ChanceWatkins The autocomplete for IDLE isn't great.